# My Python code in VS Code is not running even though i am not getting any error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My Python code in VS Code is not running even though I am not getting any error
So I did not do anything wrong I might have misclicked. I have watched all the youtube videos . In which they are saying that enable code runner from settings I did that also still not getting any output this the code that I am running-

[image]

So this is the code I am running I have even installed the code runner and ran the code with "run code" as well as run python file in terminal guys plz help me

Comment: Can you please share the error or the outcome when you run the code with "run code" or using terminal?

Comment: Hi Shubh,
Your second while loop (i.e. at line 13) looks to be an infinite loop. Just try doing a dry-run and see for yourself. [@BWallDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6227490/bwalldev) has already highlighted this point correctly.

Comment: Thanks alot for ur help buddy I dint know that it was an infinite loop apparently this was a leet code question and I did it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking before the line number will add a breakpoint, start debugging then click [image: the down] to **step into** the code, you will find `pt1 is always not equal to pt2`, which means `while pt1!=pt2` is an infinite loop. so it won't jump out then execute the `return pt1` sentence:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot buddy at first I dint know that I placed a marker that the top so it was also not debugging it and it was an infinite loop . Thanks for ur time

Comment: @ShubhAgarwal. You're welcome. happy coding:)

Answer (score 0):

Set a break point and run the code in the debugger. This will tell you what's going on!

Answer (score 0):

Your second while loop is an infinite loop. Run this and you'll see

```
def dup(nums):
    tort = nums[0]
    hare = nums[0]
    while True:
        tort = nums[tort]
        hare = nums[nums[hare]]
        if tort == hare:
            break
    
        pt1 = nums[0]
        pt2 = tort
    
        while pt1 != pt2:
            pt1 = nums[pt1]
            pt2 = nums[pt2]
            print('oh')
        
        return pt1
    
print(dup([1,2,3,4,5,6,1]))
```

Comment: Thanks alot for ur help buddy , I reviewed my code again and it was an infinite loop thanks alot for ur time

Answer (score 0):

you actually have a breakpoint set at line 1. Your code execution stops there if you intend to debug your code. If you just want to run it, remove the breakpoint by clicking on the red dot next to line 1.

[image: remove_breakpoint_here)]

If that dosen't work then try executing the file from the command line.

Comment: Thanks alot buddy I dint know I had a break point at the first line thanks alot for ur time